# (New) Century Schoolbook Font in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I recently made the switch to LuaTeX from pdfTeX. Before the switch, I used the `fouriernc` package to set the document's font to New Century Schoolbook. I've come to understand (from [this document](http://ctan.mackichan.com/info/luatex/lualatex-doc/lualatex-doc.pdf)) that one should not do this in LuaTeX and should load `fontspec` and use `\setmainfont{<font>}`. So, there are two parts to my question:

1. Why is it a bad idea to load `fouriernc` with LuaTex? I tried compiling in this way and the document compiled successfully with no (visible) problems at all.
2. If it is truly a must that one loads fonts with `fontspec`, then where can I possibly find New Century Schoolbook (or Century Schoolbook) files? In my MikTeX distribution, I thought I found them in `/fonts/tfm/public/fourier`, but I always get an error saying that the file cannot be found (yes, I quadruple checked the spelling and path). I should also add I do need this specific font; other Century fonts won't suffice unfortunately.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Use \setmainfont{Tex Gyre Bonum} which ist a free, opentype Schoolbook version which comes with texlive

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. While it is true that you cannot get the full benefit of LuaTeX if you use traditional TeX fonts, as far as I know there is no problem with doing so if those are the fonts you need and you are not relying on the additional features LuaTeX can support. Note the discussion of `luainputenc` in that document as well.

Comment: @MaxNoe: Bonum is imho a bookman clone, schola is schoolbook.

Comment: Of course, i messed them up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two possibilities.

### 1 – Use `fouriernc` with TeX Gyre Schola as text font

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont[Scale=0.93]{TeX Gyre Schola}


\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation*}
  \widehat{bcd} \ \widetilde{efg} \ \dot A \ \dot R  \ {\ddot A \check t} 
  \  \check{\mathcal{A}}\ \mathbf{\acute \imath}
\end{equation*}
some other text
\begin{equation*}
  \langle a \rangle \left\langle \frac{a}{b} \right\rangle
  \left\langle \frac{\frac{a}{b}}{c} \right\rangle
\end{equation*}
some other text
\begin{equation*}
  (x + a)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k a^{n-k} \quad\text{binomial}
\end{equation*}
square roots
\begin{equation*}
 \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}}}}}} =
 \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}}}}}}}}}{\frac{2}{3}}
\end{equation*}
Cardinal numbers and powers
\begin{equation*}
 \aleph_{0}<2^{\aleph_0}<2^{2^{\aleph_0}}\qquad
x^{\alpha} e^{\beta x^{\gamma} e^{\delta x^{\epsilon}}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### 2 – Use TeX Gyre Schola and TeX Gyre Schola Math

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont[Scale=0.93]{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setmathfont[Scale=0.93]{TeX Gyre Schola Math}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation*}
  \widehat{bcd} \ \widetilde{efg} \ \dot A \ \dot R  \ {\ddot A \check t} 
  \  \check{\mathcal{A}}\ \mathbf{\acute \imath}
\end{equation*}
some other text
\begin{equation*}
  \langle a \rangle \left\langle \frac{a}{b} \right\rangle
  \left\langle \frac{\frac{a}{b}}{c} \right\rangle
\end{equation*}
some other text
\begin{equation*}
  (x + a)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k a^{n-k} \quad\text{binomial}
\end{equation*}
square roots
\begin{equation*}
 \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}}}}}} =
 \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}}}}}}}}}{\frac{2}{3}}
\end{equation*}
Cardinal numbers and powers
\begin{equation*}
 \aleph_{0}<2^{\aleph_0}<2^{2^{\aleph_0}}\qquad
x^{\alpha} e^{\beta x^{\gamma} e^{\delta x^{\epsilon}}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. The first solution seems to do exactly what I need it to do. But, I am confused. What is the text font exactly? From the code, I deduce that it is Tex Gyre Schola. But, after having a closer inspection of the output, it looks identical to New Century Schoolbook. The only difference is that the ``quotation marks'' are different.

Also, why did you set `scale = 0.93`?

Comment: @fiziks You probably have an older version of `fontspec`; type `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Schola}`. The 0.93 factor is because `fouriernc` math fonts are 7% smaller than the normal size of New Century Schoolbook (I took the value from `fouriernc.sty`).

Comment: @egreg Could you give more details about how you obtained the `0.93` factor, please?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Actually, I dont remember. With 0.94957 I get the same x-height, but different height for uppercase; the same height for uppercase is obtained with 0.92459. The average is 0.93708. Things may have changed in four years.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your answer. The result looks almost exactly the same. A slight difference, however, can be seen in small Greek math letters like \varphi and \pi. Is there also a close equivalent to fouriernc when it comes to small Greek math letters?

Comment: @FlorianL I'm not sure what differences you're referring to.

Answer (score 3):

Standard pdflatex fonts have some glyphs not there where lualatex expects thems. This doesn't show when the text uses only ascii. But try out this document with lualatex to see the problems with fouriernc:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\begin{document}
Euro: € Sharp s: ß
\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare it with the fontspec output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\begin{document}
Euro: € Sharp s: ß
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage[lutf8]{luainputenc}` would help, right? Though it doesn't solve the problem entirely. (The documentation suggests to me that it should but it doesn't seem to do so no matter what I try.)

Comment: Yes you can resolve the problem by making every "faulty" input active and then map it like inputenc+fontenc do it to the correct position. luainputenc should do it for the glyphs in my example, load if *after* fouriernc. But luainputenc handles only a subset of unicode.

Comment: @cfr luainputenc solves the input encoding mismatch but hyphenation is wrong (the hyphenation patterns assuming unicode have already been read). Since luatex can read hyphenation patterns in a document, not just in a format (unlike classic tex or xetex) this could in theory be fixable but isn't fixed in any off the shelf package as far as I know.