# Drop-in replacement for ``fouriernc`` for LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, fourier

I have been using `fouriernc` for a while now, despite compiling with LuaLaTeX, and I very much like to look of the produced pdf files. However, upon compiling the following warning is thrown:

> Package fourier Warning: Please consider loading "fourier-otf.sty" instead of "fourier.sty" with Unicode engines LuaTeX or XeTeX, so that Type1 fonts get replaced by OpenType fonts. See file "Erewhon-Math.pdf" for more information.

If I follow the warning's advice and replace `\usepackage{fourier-otf}` by  `\usepackage{fouriernc}` in my preamble, the font in the resulting pdf file changes visibly.

I am sorry for being completely ignorant about how to handle fonts properly. – Could someone maybe tell me whether there is a fully equivalent drop-in replacement for `fouriernc` that is recommended (or more suitable) for LuaLaTeX? I would very much like to keep the looks of my documents, while also satisfying the engine...

**EDIT**

A similar question was asked and answered here: [(New) Century Schoolbook Font in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230268/new-century-schoolbook-font-in-lualatex/230274#230274).

The result looks almost exactly the same. A slight difference, however, can be seen in small Greek math letters like `\varphi` and `\pi`. Is there maybe also a close equivalent to fouriernc for small Greek math letters?

Comment: You can ignore the warning…

Comment: You can also have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/609798/is-there-an-otf-ot-ttf-version-of-the-fouriernc-math-font-otf